# Windows Phone user-agents?

Tags: windows, useragent, phone

I've been analyzing my access logs and found two very different ways Windows Phones advertise themselves. Here are two examples for a Nokia Lumia 800:

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone OS 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; NOKIA; Lumia 800)`

and

`Windows Phone Search (Windows Phone OS 7.10;NOKIA;Lumia 800;7.10;8107)`

So I'm wondering what this second form is. It appears less often than the former and seems related to some sort of "search" related feature.

Does anyone have an idea? Which App or feature will send http requests using this second UA?

Note: I know user-agents can be trivially spoofed. My question is "in what cirsumstance will an unspoofed Windows Phone device use either user-agents?"

EDIT: I've noticed that the `Windows Phone Search` variety only produces hits on images and never on anything else (html, css, js, ...). This rule out the possibility that this is just a regular user-agent used by some installs of Windows Phone. This is clearly not the web browser calling.

Comment: You've only found 2, keep looking for the others (or get more phones)

Comment: @JimB I'm not sure I follow your thoughts... You will notice that both user-agent strings come from Lumia 800 phones. I added a few observations I've made in the original question.

Comment: I thought you were presuming that there were only 2 UA strings

Answer (score 0):

Best guess: it's the search app image search function. Search - enter term - select images. It opens up a preview of the image